# "Error creating bean with name 'flyway': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?"

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, database-migration

I have `spring-boot-data-jpa` application with `PostgreSQL`.
I need to do a data migration: get data from the database, generate a sequence value, set it to an entity and save it into the database. It doesn't sound very difficult, but I'm running into such strange error:

```java
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'jdbcSequenceGenerator' defined in class path resource 
[com/mydocs/configuration/SequenceGeneratorConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcSequenceGenerator' parameter 0; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name 'flyway': Requested bean is currently in creation: 
Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
```

It looks like the error is due to the fact that I open a stream to get data from the database and generate a sequence at the same time. But I can't do without any of these actions. Help me, please, how can I solve this problem?

That `com/mydocs/configuration/SequenceGeneratorConfiguration.class` file:

```kotlin
@Configuration
class SequenceGeneratorConfiguration {
    @Bean
    fun jdbcSequenceGenerator(jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate, manager: PlatformTransactionManager): JdbcSequenceGenerator {
        val transactionTemplate = TransactionTemplate(manager)
        transactionTemplate.isolationLevel = TransactionDefinition.ISOLATION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
        transactionTemplate.propagationBehavior = TransactionDefinition.PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW
        return JdbcSequenceGenerator(jdbcTemplate, transactionTemplate)
    }
}
```

Migration class:

```kotlin
@Component
class V1689943918__Migrate_Documents(
    @Lazy private val messageRepository: MessageEntityRepository,
    private val mapper: EntityMapper,
) : BaseJavaMigration() {

    override fun migrate(context: Context) {
        messageRepository.findAllByOrderByCreatedAt().use { entities: Stream<MessageEntity> ->
            entities.forEach { migrate(it) }
        }
    }

    private fun migrate(entity: MessageEntity) {
        entity.data.attachments
            ?.map { attachmentEntity ->
                val number = generateDocumentSequence(chatId.toString())
                mapper.mapToDocumentEntity(entity.chatId, number, attachmentEntity)
            }
            ?.let { documentEntities ->
                messageRepository.save(entity.copy(documents = documentEntities))
            }
    }
}
```

SequenceGenerator:

```kotlin
class JdbcSequenceGenerator(
    private val jdbcTemplate: JdbcTemplate,
    private val transactionTemplate: TransactionTemplate
) : SequenceGenerator {

    override fun generateSequence(vararg parts: String?): Long {
        return transactionTemplate.execute {
            jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(UPSERT_SQL, Long::class.java, parts.joinToString(separator = "_"), INITIAL_VALUE)
        } ?: throw RuntimeException("Sequence generation error")
    }

    companion object {
        const val DOCUMENT_SEQUENCE_NAME = "document_sequence"
        private const val INITIAL_VALUE = 1L

        private const val UPSERT_SQL = """
            INSERT INTO _generated_sequences AS t (id, sequence) 
            VALUES (?, ?) 
            ON CONFLICT (id) DO UPDATE 
            SET sequence = t.sequence + 1 
            RETURNING sequence
        """
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just added these line to my `application.yml` and it solved my problem:

```
spring:
  main:
    allow-circular-references: true
```

Comment: It doesn't really solve it but rather hides it. You are injecting dependencies in classes that are used very early in the process which can lead to surprising results.